# Use differnet Lottie animations Without making http requests

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, lottie

I'm working on a small game related to dice. I have 6 Lottie animations, each for a die face.
When the user click 'roll' a random die face is up. Hence a random Lottie animation.
The problem is each animation file (json file) is 320 kb. Whenever the user clicks roll the website makes an http request that could take up to 300-400ms.
I'm looking for a way to use these animations without http requests. In other words whenever i click roll the animation renders smoothly. Also i prefer the the solution would be PWA friendly for future plans.

[image: the game I'm creating]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the requests on page-load, and store the results in LocalStorage, for usage whenever you need it.

```
localStorage.setItem('dice-face-1', JSON.stringify(LottieContent));
const diceFace1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dice-face-1'));
localStorage.setItem('dice-face-2', ...
```

[LocalStorage documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Further notes: This would have the die faces "lottie-data" stored for the users next visit to your game as well :)

And you then need to be able to invalidate the cached data as well, so when you update your lottie-data the user also get the data that you intent.

```
const newVersion = 1.03;
localStorage.setItem('lottie-data-version', 1.02);
const lottieDataVersion = localStorage.getItem('lottie-data-version');
if(lottieDataVersion < newVersion){
  localStorage.removeItem('dice-face-1');
  ...(invalidate other data)
}
```

Comment: I thought of this. But i didn't figure how to use the actual json to render the animation since the Lottie API requires a path to be provided. So how can i use the Json to render the animation?

Comment: I've had some luck using the .loadAnimation() method, only supplying a JSON string.

An awful workaround could be to supply an empty json-file in the initial path-definition, and then afterward use the .loadAnimation() to inject the correct data.

If that doesn't get your luck going, you might need to look into the depths of using the "LottieCompositionFactory" that this article goes through(but i do not have experience in this method):
[Medium, Loading Lottie’s animation from local storage](https://medium.com/dev-today/loading-lotties-animation-from-local-storage-93ff29f21296)

Comment: I'll take a look in the  "LottieCompositionFactory". Could you please provide me a sample of the method you've luck with? Also thanks!

Comment: I used animationData property instead of path and i passed a JSON object and it WORKED! can't thank you enough!

Comment: That sounds awesome!! You're very welcome, and i'm glad i could point you in the somewhat right direction :)